# Trying to identify a graphic design style/concept

Tags: style-identification

I am interested in identifying a particular graphic-design concept, if it exists (and is not just my imagination).
Two examples that I can think of are:

- The background of the cover art on the AC/DC album *Black Ice:*

  [image]
- The old (pre-2010) logo design of Brut brand aftershave.

  [image]

It’s a dirty masculine tattoo or imprint kind of look.
Is this a defined style/concept?

Comment: Art deco maybe? No idea where you get "dirty, masculine" from.. both your examples employ primarily high-contrast geometric shapes.